# JavaScript: right switch-case statement

Tags: javascript

My code is such:

```
switch(typeof src) {
    case 'string':
    case 'boolean':
        return String(src).toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    case 'object':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

but code checker say that: `n unconditional "break" statement shall terminate every non-empty switch-clause`

will it be right and normal if I will write it so?

```
switch(typeof src) {
    case 'string':
    case 'boolean':
        return String(src).toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        break;
    case 'object':
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
        // in default i need it or not?
}
```

or I missed somewhat else?

Comment: which codechecker you use?

Comment: use the 2nd form. it doesn't matter really (since return stops fall-through), but whatever.

Comment: Well, why don't you ask your code checker ? :)

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck - i need to wait till 24:00 when it will re-check... )

Comment: The given answers are... should have been comments... Simply return will exit the function/statement not continue below. In the case of a default... By the looks of your code.. If i hand it a number.. It would not do anything.. So you do want a default value as a safety net

Answer (score 3):

Your code checker is wrong then, because a `return` terminates the entire function in which the switch statement resides.
Anything after a `return` (like the `break` it wants you to put there) will be unreachable and never executed.

Whether or not this is beautiful or good practise is debatable, but I would say it is OK.

If you do not have a `return` statement or anything else that terminates the current block or jumps out of it (like `continue` inside a loop), **then** you **usually want to** put a `break` and the end of each `case` block to prevent fallthrough, but there are actually cases where you want fallthrough.

So your code checker is more of an opinion checker really.

Answer (score 0):

*No, break statement is not necessary if you return from a default case.*

You must add break statement for all your cases which you want to operate and stop switch's work, otherwise default is operated returning from function.

Comment: You don't need a break when you return from *anywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Switch Pattern from "JavaScript Patterns" by Stoyan Stefanov.

```
 var inspect_me = 0,
     result = '';
 switch (inspect_me) {
     case 0:
         result = "zero";
         break;
     case 1:
         result = "one";
         break;
     default:
         result = "unknown";
 }
```